# How to use custom fonts for WiX installer UI dialogs?

Tags: wix, installation

I'm using WiX toolset 3.6 to build a simple MSI installer, but I'd like to customize to look and feel of the installer UI.

I've found plenty of resources on customizing the images, replacing the strings, setting the font for those strings, etc., but I did not find anything on embedding a custom font and using it as the font family (over existing system fonts).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI UI doesn't support loading fonts. You can use a bootstrapper application in a WiX Burn bundle and do anything the OS supports.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, is there a way to know what fonts are safe to use?

Comment: No, there's nothing in MSI UI to let you query installed fonts. MSI UI is really basic.